# Проблемы с нативной рекламой в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Пытаюсь добавить нативную рекламу в RecyclerView по вот этому [примеру](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample) и возникают проблемы, после того как я попытался добавить рекламу в список под индексом "6". При включении приложения, список перемещается к первой рекламе, т.е. к позиции "6", хотя по идее без касаний он должен оставаться в самом начале.

P.S. Возможно не совсем понятно что я тут объяснял, поэтому оставлю [это видео здесь](https://rutube.ru/video/38fca71053c7f9a8481add0ef4712be8/). В видео я включаю приложение и после нескольких секунд список перемещается к первой рекламе и мне приходится вручную перемещаться в начало списка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, нашел решение сам. Как оказалось, подобная проблема, когда RecyclerView скролится к первой рекламе существует на некоторых версиях android support lib. И для того чтобы решить эту проблему нужно добавить вот этот атрибут - `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` в макет RecyclerView.

Эта строка обозначает, что все потомки от макета родителя не будут получать больше внимания